# Insertar 2 Array en tabla mysql

Tags: php

He buscado la solución aqui y en varios lugares pero aun no la encuentro. Si alguien puede darme "luz" en esto se lo agradecería:

> Tengo 2 array, uno de horas y otro de dias

El de Horas:

```
Array ( [0] => 12:00:00 [1] => 12:30:00 [2] => 12:40:00 [3] => 13:00:00 [4] => 13:30:00 [5] => 14:00:00)
```

El de dias:

```
Array ([0] => Lunes [1] => Miercoles [2] => Viernes)
```

Ahora bien. Necesito insertaros en mi tabla MySql(mariadb) "trabajo (campo dia)" y que quede de la siguiente manera por ejemplo en el dia Lunes

Dia Lunes:

```
12:00:00
12:30:00
13:00:00
13:30:00
```

Como verán esto producira multiple inserciones en la tabla de una vez lo cual es tambien otra cosa que busco. Ordenar los Array y Insertar El Dia junto con los Horarios correspondiente a ese dia en una sola inserción.
Trabaj0 con PHP 7.2 y Mysql MariaDB

Desde ya muchas Gracias

Answer (score 1):

que tal si usas una tabla para hora y otra para días. Luego haces una tabla de muchos a muchos para de esta forma guardar horas para un día sin repetir los datos.

Ademas a esto, puedes especificar que la tabla intermedia Día_Hora, tenga los 2 campos id, como primarios para que no pueda existir por ejemplo: el día lunes con el horario 13:00 repetido 2 veces.

Te dejo un ejemplo del diagrama de base de datos

[image: Diagrama de base de datos]